# Insert array in multidimensional array dynamically with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I’m struggling with array manipulation in php. I have two multidimensional arrays and I would like to insert each element of the second one into each element of the first one. I tried a lot of different native php functions to try to manipulate my two arrays but it seems like I am at a dead end.

I'll be very thankfull for any kind of help

Here are my two arrays :

1.

```
2019 => [
    'Sweden' => [
        'population' => '1000'
    ]
]
2020 => [
    'Sweden' => [
        'population' => '1500'
    ]
]
```

2. 

```
O => [
    'Facebook' => [
        'accounts' => '340'],
    'Instagram' => [
        'accounts' => '750'],
    'Linkedin' => [
        'accounts' => '560'],
]
1 => [
    'Facebook' => [
        'accounts' => '290'],
    'Instagram' => [
        'accounts' => '800'],
    'Linkedin' => [
        'accounts' => '378'],
]
```

Now what I would like to have as a final array will be :

```
2019 => [
    'Sweden' => [
        'population' => '1000',
        'Facebook' => [
            'accounts' => '340'],
        'Instagram' => [
            'accounts' => '750'],
        'Linkedin' => [
            'accounts' => '560'],
    ]
]
2020 => [
    'Sweden' => [
        'population' => '1500',
        'Facebook' => [
            'accounts' => '290'],
        'Instagram' => [
            'accounts' => '800'],
        'Linkedin' => [
            'accounts' => '378'],
    ]
]
```

Comment: Show your code please (show to us that you have attempted to do it)

Comment: Can the first array have countries other than Sweden? If there are multiple countries, how should the values from the second array be merged?

Comment: The function you're looking for is `array_merge()`. Loop over the two arrays in parallel, and merge the elements of the second array into the corresponding elements of the first array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, you want to set up an algorithm like this:
**Note:** If your arrays are of variable nature, edit this algorithm accordingly.

```
$array1 = [
    2019 => [
        'Sweden' => [
            'population' => '1000',
        ],
    ],
    2020 => [
        'Sweden' => [
            'population' => '1500',
        ],
    ],
];

$array2 = [
    0 => [
        'Facebook' => [
            'accounts' => '340',
        ],
        'Instagram' => [
            'accounts' => '750',
        ],
        'Linkedin' => [
            'accounts' => '560',
        ],
    ],
    1 => [
        'Facebook' => [
            'accounts' => '290',
        ],
        'Instagram' => [
            'accounts' => '800',
        ],
        'Linkedin' => [
            'accounts' => '378',
        ],
    ],
];

$country = 'Sweden';

$orderedIndex = 0;
foreach ($array1 as $index => $item) {
    foreach ($array2[$orderedIndex] as $social => $accounts) {
        $array1[$index][$country][$social] = $accounts;
    }
    $orderedIndex++;
}

dd($array1); // result
```